# Embed the image build time in code

Tags: c, compilation

We constantly run into issues where we are running different C images on different machines. Since our code is still in production, we keep generating binaries that folks use. Often lot of time is spent in debugging only to learn later that the binaries were incorrect.

I was wondering if there is some mechanism with which I could print the date and time when I had compiled the code then we could use that to ensure that all binaries are the same.

Any idea on how I can do this in C? I want to print the time and date when I built this image along with the version number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` macros are predefined by the compiler with the date and time that a C program is built. These are just string literals of the format `"Mmm dd yyyy"` and `"hh:mm:ss"` respectively, so should be easy to use with any logging or printing system. (These macros are defined in the C11 standard section 6.10.8.1)

Comment: As in `printf("%s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__);`

Comment: @DoxyLover: that would print the values; you could also consider: `const char build_time[] = __DATE__ " " __TIME__;` and you might want to prefix it with a recognizable pattern (historically, SCCS used `@(#)`, while RCS used names like `$Build: … $` with the value appearing where I placed `…`).  The `what` command from SCCS and the `ident` command from RCS can find these patterns and print what follows.

Answer (score 2):

**It's called versioning:**

First, add a dedicated source file which uses the compile time strings `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

For example:

```
printf("%s %s",__DATE__,__TIME__);
```

Or if you want to be able to extract information from these strings:

```
char _date[] = __DATE__; // the format is "Jan  1 2000"
char _time[] = __TIME__; // the format is "00:00:00"
// Now use these variables to extract the data...
```

Then, make sure that whenever you change **any file** in your project, the dedicated source file will be recompiled. You can typically apply this in your project settings *pre-build* configuration, by invoking a script which deletes the object file corresponding to the dedicated source file.

For example, let's assume that the name of the dedicated source file is `version.c`, the extension of object files is `obj`, and the location of object files relatively to the project is `debug\obj`.

If you are running your build tools over Windows, then you may invoke the following batch file:

```
set VERSION_FILE="debug\obj\version.obj"
if exist %VERSION_FILE% del /q %VERSION_FILE%
```